# cos and sin give wrong answers in C

Tags: c, trigonometry

Hi I am trying to find a x and y direction by using sin and cos in C, I have included math.h and compile with -lm.
I know that "rad" gives right result, but the next line does not, I have been staring at this for hours and search the questions here, can anybody see something wrong with this.

```
double cos_sinY(int cos_sinus, double x, double y)
{
    double rad, y_value, pi = 3.1415;//8979323846
    rad = (double)cos_sinus/180*pi;
    y_value = x*(sin(rad))+y*(cos(rad));
    return y_value;
}
```

Comment: Check your formula and then data type.

Comment: What O/P were you expecting? What O/P did you get? No one is a magician here to guess on that. You are using floating point numbers so probably that has an effect.Good Read: http://floating-point-gui.de

Comment: What are you trying to compute again?

Comment: Rejecting. This is a math question, rather than programming related.

Comment: Tanks for the help!To start with x and y are numbers on a plane, for example (1,0), and then I add for example -90°, and then call this function with these tree numbers (-90, 1, 0), and have two function one to give me new x value and other for y value, which is the function above.

Comment: @cabe Yes, but what are the new x and y values supposed to *be*?

Comment: It is HIGHLY unlikely that cos/sin functions give significant errors - the 7th decimal place may well be a little bit out, but I'm guessing you're not referring to that, so you are probably doing something wrong!

Comment: Yes you are right Mats, there was an error, thanks all

Comment: State example values that you provide for `cos_sinus`, `x`, and `y`, the value that you expect to be returned, and the value that is actually returned. Provide at least two sets of such example values, at least one of which is non-trivial.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs What? This question actually includes a C function. It is a bad question, but certainly not for the reason “this is math”.

Comment: @PascalCuoq, I do distinguish between bad questions and math ones, and according to the comment on the only answer, it is a math question.

Comment: `3.1415` is far less precise than what `double` can represent pi

Answer (score 1):

Given the mathematical formula provided by the questioner, “x_1 = x_0*cos(Alpha) - y_0*sin(Alpha), y_1 = x_0*sin(Alpha) + y_0*cos(Alpha)”, I tested code in the question with several values. In each case, the code produced the value I expected.

This formula is the formula for rotating a point in the plane. Rotation is in the direction mathematicians regarding as positive (counterclockwise, (1, 0) rotated 90º is (0, 1)).

Example:  cos_sinus(30, .3, .6) produces .669616.

If this is not what the questioner observes, then there is some other problem in their code that lies beyond what they have disclosed in the question.

The code should be modified to use a more accurate value for π, such as 3.1415926535897932384626433, rather than 3.1415.

Comment: Hi and thanks it works like this:                                    x_1 = x_0*cos(Alpha) - y_0*sin(Alpha)   and                               y_1 = x_0*sin(Alpha) + y_0*cos(Alpha).

Comment: @Eric Postpischil , why cos(4.71239) is giving me -1.83697e-16 which should be 0. I tried cmath and math.h but got the same results.

Comment: @FadySamann: The cosine of 4.71239 is about 0.00000101961531. Why would you think it should be 0? The cosine of 1.5•π is 0, but 4.71239 is not 1.5•π. It is just near 1.5•π, and the cosine of numbers near 1.5•π are near 0. Further, the number you have in your program is probably not 4.71239. It is probably just printed as 4.71239 because you only printed a few digits of it. The internal number is different, and its cosine is about −1.83697•10^−16.

Comment: @EricPostpischil what I am passing to the cos() is 270*(M_PI/180). 4.71238898038469 must be the radian of 270. That is why I think that cos() should give me 0!!

Comment: @FadySamann: `M_PI` is not π. It is a numeral that results in a `double` value close to π. Numerical formats generally cannot represent irrational numbers. In particular, the format used for `double` commonly represents numbers as multiples of powers of two, including negative powers of two such as 2^−52. Further, when the `double` that results from `M_PI` is divided by 180, the result is probably not representable in the `double` format, so it is rounded to the nearest representable value. And when that is multiplied by 270, the result is rounded again.

Comment: @FadySamann: The result of all those operations is likely 4.7123889803846896739969452028162777423858642578125, which is not 1.5•π, so its cosine is not zero.